# How do I prevent RMarkdown from interpreting math as MathJax?

Tags: knitr, mathjax, tex

I have a huge tibble that I'm pulling a few kable tables out of. They're all open ended answers to a question. A couple of the answers are "$$$" or "I don't have the $$$$".

When I run the code locally, I get what I expect (a clean table of answers that were provided) but when I try to knit to HTML it is being interpreted as "MathJax" and showing raw HTML instead of the table:

[image: Mathjax as rendered][[image: source2]

I can't seem to reproduce the exact behavior (only breaking in the HTML, not when I render the block in RStudio), but if I add some dollar signs to a faintly random tibble and generate a `kable :

```
habits <- tribble(
    ~Habit, ~Description,
    "Q1_apple", "$$$", 
    "Q1_pineapple", "Random Thought", 
    "Q1_passionfruit", "$$$$", 
    "Q1_honeydew", "Not even pretending this makes sense."
  ) 

kable(habits)
```

The error I get suggests that it is hitting the same problem -- TeX wants to interpret the "$$$" as an equation:

```
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math '$ </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="text-align:left;"> Q1_bathe </td>
     <td style="text-align:left;"> Random Thought </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="text-align:left;"> Q1_hair </td>
     <td style="text-align:left;"> ', rendering as TeX:
  $ </td>
  ^
  unexpected '$'
```

How do I tell TeX (or Knitr?) to ignore any potential math in this particular Chunk?

Comment: It sounds like this might be a bug: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1182

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a flag to just say "don't interpret this as math" but I can add spaces around the $ which works for me:

```
kable(
habits %>% 
  mutate(Description = str_replace_all(Description, "\\$", " $ "))
)
```